# Standard pagination not working

Tags: structure, pagination

I'm having issues getting pagination to work, using the same settings I usually do but paging doesn't change the content / listed entries.

I've stripped down my template for testing and currently have this:

```
    {exp:channel:entries 
        channel="blog_entries" 
        limit="12" 
        orderby="date" 
        sort="desc" 
        paginate="top" 
        paginate_base="blog/" 
        dynamic="no"
    }

        <article>
            <a href="{page_url}" title="{title}">{title}</a>
            <span class="post-date">{entry_date format="%m.%d.%y"}</span>
        </article>

        {paginate}<p class="pagination load-more">{pagination_links}</p>{/paginate}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

I tried disabling extensions to test if any were interfering but then I get a 404 on pagination URLs.

Also, this part is really odd, but one minute it's displaying posts by date in descending order, and the latest post shows first and then I'll refresh as I'm testing, and it starts from a different date, as if it's lost a bunch of posts.

This one is correct:
[image]

And this is what I randomly get:
[image]

**Note that yes, these are both the same page, page 1.

EE v2.7.3 Build 20131210

Addons I have installed:
[image: Addons Screenshot]

Any ideas what could be going on here? Would any of the extensions I have installed be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you really need the "paginate_base" parameter?

Comment: Good question, I read in the EE forums that there could be problems without it.  I've never used it before and it doesn't seem to make any difference with or without it as far as this issue goes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `dynamic="no"` in your parameters. Pagination depends on the URL, which in turn means the channel entries tags need to be dynamic.

Comment: Without dynamic="no" - the entries do not display at all.  Note: these are structure listings - `{exp:channel:entries channel="your-listing-channel" dynamic="no"}` is the proper entries tag for structure listings per the documentation.

Comment: Ah right, I think you'll need to use Freebie then - I see you already have it installed.

Comment: Hmmmm, how would you use freebie to fix pagination with structure? I'm not sure what you mean? Thanks again.